# Use XSLT to transform XML with conditionals upon node count

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove nodes from an XML file. Using just one XSLT for each of my XML I need to make decisions in the XSLT based upon the number of children of the document element.

```
<root>
  <branch>
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </branch>
<root>
```

should transform into

```
  <branch>
  </branch>
```

but

```
<root>
  <branch>
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </branch>
  <branch>
    <foo>baz</foo>
<root>
```

into

```
<root>
  <branch>
  </branch>
  <branch>
  </branch>
<root>
```

That is, the root element should be removed if its (only) child can act as the new document root of the result XML after applying XSLT. The `<foo>` nodes have to be removed in every occurence.

Is there a way to perform this operation with a single XSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root[*[2]]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root[* and not(*[2])]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="branch/foo"/>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, seems to work in my sandbox. I'm just learning XSLT right now: Do regular expressions like [* and not...] require XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Regular expression for string matching are only supported in XSLT and XPath 2.0. However I have only used XSLT 1.0 element match patterns as `match="root[*[2]]"` is simply a short form for `match="root[child::*[2]]"` meaning matches `root` elements with at least two child elements of any name.

Answer (score 2):

**A simpler, shorter and more generic (no element names hardcoded) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*[not(*[2])]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/node()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the first provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<root>
    <branch>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </branch>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<branch></branch>
```

**When the same transformation is applied on the second provided XML document** (again needed to be corrected for well-formedness):

```
<root>
    <branch>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </branch>
    <branch>
        <foo>baz</foo>
    </branch>
</root>
```

**again the wanted, correct output is produced**:

```
<root>
    <branch></branch>
    <branch></branch>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every node "as-is".
2. There are two templates that override the identity template for specific nodes and process these nodes in different ways.
3. The first overriding template matches a top element that doesn't have a second element child. It doesn't copy the element itself, but processes its children.
4. The second overriding template matches any element that is a grand-child of the top element. This template doesn't have a body, which means that all such matched element are ignored and not included in the output (in other words -- "deleted")

**Do note**:

This transformation can be applied to *any* XML document, regardless of the element names in it, and still produces the wanted, correct result.

**For example**, when applied on this XML document:

```
<t>
    <b>
        <f>brrr</f>
    </b>
    <b>
        <f>bzzz</f>
    </b>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
</t>
```

**Contrast this to the result produced by the currently - accepted answer**:

```
<t>
    <b>
        <f>brrr</f>
    </b>
    <b>
        <f>bzzz</f>
    </b>
</t>
```